# Retrieve all selected options from a multi select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

```
<select id="abc" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">C</option>
</select>
```

I wish to retrieve all selected values.

No matter what I try it seems to only give me the value of the selected item that is lowest in the list. So if I select A, B, and C it will only return C.

These are the things I have tried:

```
$('#abc').val()
$('#abc').text()
$('#abc :selected').val()
$('#abc :selected').text()
$('#abc option:selected').val()
$('#abc option:selected').text()
```

The version of jQuery I am using is v1.9.1

Comment: All the answers so far are also only returning one value

Comment: the select is in a td, i dont know if this makes a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop through all selected element within select using `.each()` to get access them individually:

```
$('#abc :selected').each(function(){ 
    console.log($(this).text()); 
});
```

or to get the values in array

```
var selectedvals = $('#abc').val();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/spwSL/

Comment: Did you mean `#abc :selected` which is not equivalent to `#abc:selected`?

Comment: @RSM Please see rest of answer.

Comment: I have, unfortunately on my console it only returns one value still.

Comment: Check the fiddle. `selectedvals` is an array of values. Something else is wrong on your end.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var values = $("#abc option:selected").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()` to store the values in an array and use it:

```
var vals = $('#abc :selected').map(function(){ 
    return this.value;
}).get();

console.log(vals);
```

or this way:

```
var vals = [];
$('#abc :selected').each(function(){ 
    vals.push(this.value);
});
console.log(vals);
```

Answer (score 1):

For a multiple select when `this` references the `select` element, you cannot use `this.value` as that will return only one value. As @MilindAnantwar has noted above `$(this)` will return an array. If you were interested in a comma-delimited string rather than an array you can use the `join()` array method to join the various values into a string:

```
var selectedOpts = $( '#abc' ).val().join( ',' );
```

Otherwise you would have to access the elements by array notation `[0], [1], .... [n-1]`.